# How to solve "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column" without adding the column into "group by"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

table:

| id | action | project_id | created_on | last_updated_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Update | 123 | 2021.1.1 | 2021.5.3 |
| 2 | creation | 123 | 2021.1.4 | 2021.5.2 |
| 3 | Update | 123 | 2021.1.3 | 2021.5.1 |
| 4 | Update | 456 | 2021.2.1 | 2021.6.3 |
| 5 | Update | 456 | 2021.2.2 | 2021.6.2 |
| 6 | creation | 456 | 2021.2.3 | 2021.6.1 |

I would like to get a map of `project` and its most recently created `Update` action's `last_updated_on`.

My statement is

```
select project_id, last_updated_on 
from table
where action = "Update"
group by project_id
order by created_on desc
limit 1
```

But I got the error of `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`.

I cannot change the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` atrribute.

And in my use case I think I cannot add `last_updated_on` into the `group by` either.

I also tried

```
select 
    project_id, 
    (select last_updated_on where created_on = max(created_on)) as "last_updated_on"
    .
    .
    .
```

but the error still occurred.

Hope someone can help me.
Tnanks in advance!

Update:

Desired result of the example table:

| project_id | last_updated_on |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021.5.1 |
| 456 | 2021.6.2 |

Explanation:

1. For `project_id = 123`, row 1 and 3's `action` are `update`,
2. after `order by created_on desc limit 1`, row 3 is selected, whose `last_updated_on` is `2021.5.1`.

Comment: Do you want to display projects with no UPDATE action, or just omit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select project_id, last_updated_on
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by project_id 
                              order by last_updated_on desc) as rn
  from t
  where action = 'Update'
) x
where rn = 1
order by created_on
```

Will show the last Update action for each project. Projects with no Update action at all won't show up.

Comment: just about going there... but they want the Created by column as the final output ORDER

Comment: @DRapp Just add `ORDER BY created_on`.

Comment: They probably want the created_on in the output to follow along WHAT the value was as well.  I would add to your column list too.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you so much for your help. I believe that is what I need, but just one question: shouldn't `order by last_updated_on desc` be `order by created_on desc`? Because I would like to get the `last_updated_on` value of the most recently `created` action of `update`.

Comment: @powerseed It seems you want to filter by a relationship of the rows... that I fail to understand. I think that you could clarify that by adding the exact **expected result** to the question.

Comment: @TheImpaler Updated. Please take a look. Thanks!